# C# - WInForms - Dispose of old graphics at redrawn event

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm following a tutorial to get the basics of dealing with a paint event using windows forms.

So far the program kind of works, but any update of the graphics is not deleting the previously drawn lines (the graphics is not being disposed of).

The original tutorial used `Refresh`, but that didn't seem to work and I replaced it with `Invalidate`+`Update`.

Also, setting the graphics control to `this.CreateGraphics()` wasn't working and I switched it to `panel2.CreateGraphics()` (I also tried `e.Graphics` without results).

```
namespace GraphicsTutorialV1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Graphics g = null;

        static int start_x, start_y;
        static int end_x, end_y;

        static int my_angle = 0;
        static int my_length = 0;
        static int my_increment = 0;
        static int num_lines = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num_lines);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out my_angle);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out my_length);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out my_increment);

            start_x = (panel2.Width / 2);
            start_y = (panel2.Height / 2);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            myPen.Width = 1;
            g = panel2.CreateGraphics();
            //g = e.Graphics;

            for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
            {
                drawLine();
            }
        }

        private void drawLine()
        {
            int temp;
            Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out temp);
            my_angle = my_angle + temp;
            Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out temp);
            my_length = my_length + temp;

            end_x = (int)(start_x + Math.Cos(my_angle * Math.PI / 180) * my_length);
            end_y = (int)(start_y + Math.Sin(my_angle * Math.PI / 180) * my_length);

            Point[] points =
            {
                new Point(start_x, start_y),
                new Point(end_x, end_y)
            };

            start_x = end_x;
            start_y = end_y;

            g.DrawLines(myPen, points);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num_lines);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out my_angle);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out my_length);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out my_increment);

            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't store the Graphic object. Just use the `e.Graphics` supplied in the paint event.  If you want the panel to paint, you have to use the panel's paint event.

Comment: Using CreateGraphics() to paint is wrong in 99.9% of all cases.  If that tutorial recommended that then stop using it right away.  Use the panel's Paint event instead.  And its Invalidate() method to trigger a repaint.  You now fall in the pit of success, the panel's BackColor property gets the job done.

Comment: There is a Tutorial from Micrsoft that starts like that using a FillEllipse as a brush..Arrgh.

Comment: You can pass out the (correct) e.Graphics in the drawLine(); call: drawLine(e.Graphics);

Comment: @Hans Passant you were right, I had mistakenly used the paint event of the form instead of that of the panel. Once corrected everything started making sense, e.Graphics and Refresh() are working and all is fine. I would accept your answer if you want to post one.

Comment: I've already posted far too many CreateGraphics answers to want to support another one.  Just post it yourself and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant what is it? Self apprisal? Wouldn't it be better to point him to one of your thousands answers?☺

Comment: Hmm, those answers were meant for others to find.   The point of this web site.  That somebody can find them, or didn't search for them, does not make it my job.  I'd say it is "better" when you found them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code was that the drawing instructions were included in the paint event for the form. By setting the drawing in the paint event for the panel and then setting the graphics to the standard paint event for it everything worked out. Also, Refresh started to work.